# Regex Ignore if between certain characters

Tags: java, regex

Say I have a string:

```
"ABC+DF" + someVar + exp(A+B)
```

I would like to match the + signs before and after some var and not match on ones in double quotes or inside an exp().

Is there a regex way to match only the + signs not in quotes or in the exp()?

Update:

You can assume everything inside exp() should be ignored.  Maybe that is another way of thinking about it.  Anything in between quotes or exp() should be ignored from the regex.

Regex would be used in java String::split method. I am unsure about which platform that would be.

Comment: What's your regex platform?

Comment: You could try to match anything, of course ungreedy, between the two vars!

Comment: In PCRE you can use [this](https://regex101.com/r/QrX2iB/1): `(?:"(?:[^"]|\\.)*"|\([^)]++\))(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\+`

Comment: Whats going to happen with something like `exp("A)"+B)` ?

Comment: can you please write down the expected result

Comment: @x15 `(?:("(?:[^"]|\\.)*")|\((?:(?1)|[^)])+\))(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\+` resolves that issue in PCRE, but again, needs clarification from OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this in Java with `replaceAll + split` operations:

```
jshell> String s = "\"ABC+DF\" + someVar + exp(A+B)";
s ==> "\"ABC+DF\" + someVar + exp(A+B)"

jshell> s.replaceAll("(\"[^\"]*\"|exp\\h*\\([^)]*\\))|\\h*\\+\\h*", "$1\0").split("\0+");
$15 ==> String[3] { "\"ABC+DF\"", "someVar", "exp(A+B)" }
```

- Regex used in `replaceAll` matches and captures the part we want to ignore in group #1 on left hand side of alternation. It then replaces match with `$1\0` where `\0` is a NUL byte (ASCII: 0).
- Regex used in `split` just splits on one or more NUL bytes i.e. `\0`.

[RegEx Demo of `replaceAll`](https://regex101.com/r/0VBJdk/2)

Comment: Awesome thanks.  Could you provide a little more explanation on what exactly is going on here.  Trying to learn regex and am struggling to get exactly what you are doing.  Looks like you have 3 matching "*", exp(*) and +.  Then you are replacing it with something to allow you to split?

Comment: Yeh @Chris in `replaceAll` this regex matches a quoted string OR an `exp` section or else a `+`. Note that we are capturing a quoted string OR an `exp` section in group #1. In replacement we use `$1` (back reference of our captured group) and append a NUL byte to it. We split it by NUL byte to get our desired result. Please check explanation of the demo link to get lot more details.